# Oracle - 32 bit client, 64 bit server - ADODB Connection to specify 32 bit drivers?

Tags: windows, oracle, asp-classic, 32bit-64bit, adodb

**STAGE1:** W2003/64 running classic ASP app (in IIS6) talking to 64 bit Oracle on same machine. All is well !

**STAGE2:** The classic ASP app needs to talk to some COM objects which cannot run in 64 bit. *Hmmm*.

**STAGE3:** Change IIS so that it runs the classic ASP process as 32 bit. Now not able to talk to Oracle.

**WHAT TO DO ?**

I installed the Oracle 32 bit 'Instant Client' but on accessing an ASP page I get this :

```
ADODB.Connection error '800a0e7a'

Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.
```

The connection string looks like this :

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=ORCL;User Id=FOO;Password=BAR;
```

And that is unchanged from when the classic ASP was running happily in a 'all 64' environment.

Is there some way I should change the connection string to say "hey, there's a 32-client interface now so use that instead because you're a 32 bit process" ?

Is there something else I should have done different ?

Comment: I suspect that you may be able to do this is you use a full version on the `Provider=` but I'm not 100%

Comment: @PreetSangha thank you for your comment but can you explain a little more please ? I did try both OraOLEDB.Oracle.1 and OraOLEDB.Oracle.2 (without really knowing what I was doing but I'd seen that done elsewhere) and as far as I could see that didn't help. Appreciate your comment and if you could provide more details that would be great.

Comment: See this oracle support thread - does it help: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2497819

Comment: Check if `ORCL` data source present in [32-bit ODBC settings](http://superuser.com/questions/419832/how-can-i-open-the-32-bit-odbc-data-source-administrator-in-windows-7-64-bit).

Comment: Have you enabled 32 bit applications in your app pool? https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1114/how-to-enable-32-bit-application-pool-iis-7-dedicatedvps.aspx